# Multiple Cassandra node goes down

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

WE have a 12 node cassandra cluster across 2 different datacenter. We are migrating the data from sql DB to cassandra through a net application and there is another .net app thats reads data from the cassandra. Off recently we are seeing one or the other node going down (nodetool status shows DN and the service is stopped on it). Below is the output of the nodetool status. WE have to start the service to again get it working but it stops again.

```
https://ibb.co/4P1T453
```

Path to the log:  https://pastebin.com/FeN6uDGv

Comment: Please can you add the relevant log snippets in the question directly, rather than linking to other sites?

Comment: can you please share your "cassandra.yaml" file belongs to any of the Down nodes?

Comment: WARN  [main] 2019-04-24 00:05:30,075 NativeLibrary.java:187 - Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
WARN  [main] 2019-04-24 00:05:30,075 StartupChecks.java:127 - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  [main] 2019-04-24 00:05:30,076 StartupChecks.java:160 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.

Comment: INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-04-24 00:02:08,962 HintsService.java:220 - Paused hints dispatch
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-04-24 00:02:08,975 Server.java:176 - Stop listening for CQL clients
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-04-24 00:02:08,976 Gossiper.java:1530 - Announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-04-24 00:02:08,977 StorageService.java:2255 - Node /10.10.52.21 state jump to shutdown

Comment: INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2019-04-24 00:02:10,979 MessagingService.java:984 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-/10.10.52.21] 2019-04-24 00:02:10,980 MessagingService.java:1338 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread

Comment: @MarkOrmesher: log snipped from the node showing down.

Comment: Cassandra.yaml file - https://pastebin.com/hwQVKhdd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So in looking through your pastebin, I see a few things that can be adjusted.

First I'm reasonably sure that this is your primary issue:

```
Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out,
especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
```

From [GNU Error Codes](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html):

> Macro: int ENOMEM
>
> “Cannot allocate memory.” The system cannot allocate more virtual
>   memory because its capacity is full.

```
-Xms12G, -Xmx12G, -Xmn3000M,
```

How much RAM is on your instance?  From what I'm seeing your node is dying from an OOM (Out of Memory error).  My guess is that you're designating too much RAM to the heap, and there isn't enough for the OS/page-cache.  In fact, I wouldn't designate much more than 50%-60% of RAM to the heap.

For example, I mostly build instances on 16GB of RAM, and I've found that a 10GB max heap is about as high as you'd want to go on that.

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

In fact, as you're using CMS GC, I wouldn't go higher than 8GB for max heap size.

```
Maximum number of memory map areas per process (vm.max_map_count) 65530 is too low,
recommended value: 1048575, you can change it with sysctl.
```

This means you haven't adjusted your `limits.conf` or `sysctl.conf`.  Check through the guide ([DSE 6.0 - Recommended Production Settings](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/config/configRecommendedSettings.html#configRecommendedSettings__tuning-java-garbage-collection-cstar)), but generally it's a good idea to add the following to these files:

**/etc/limits.conf**

```
* - memlock unlimited
* - nofile 100000
* - nproc 32768
* - as unlimited
```

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
vm.max_map_count = 1048575
```

Note: After adjusting sysctl.conf, you'll want to run a `sudo sysctl -p` or reboot.

```
Is swap disabled? : false,
```

You *will* want to disable swap.  If Cassandra starts swapping contents of RAM to disk, things will get really slow.  Run a `swapoff -a` and then edit `/etc/fstab` and remove any swap entries.

**tl;dr; Summary**

- Set your initial and max heap sizes to 8GB (heap new size is fine).
- Modify your `limits.conf` an `sysctl.conf` files appropriately.
- Disable swap.
- It's also a good idea to get on the latest version of 3.11 (3.11.4).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Here is the RAM info:[cassandra_user@TELXCASS06 install]$ free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         128652       15324       38135        3513       75192      109055
Swap:          4095         243        3852

Comment: I will go through the edits that you suggested. Also we are using old GC with max heap size of 12 GB. We are planning to change GC to G1 and max heap size of 64GB. Do you think that will help?